# Need three variables in my URL

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I have 3 variables in my URL I need on my website: `page`, `x`, and `action`.

Like this:

```
/?page=category&x=geografi&action=succes
```

I wrote:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /([a-zA-Z0-9]+)
   RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?page=$1

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/
   RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ index.php?page=$1
</IfModule>
```

With that code, I get the page variable right, but I need the two others...

Comment: Are these being pulled from a directory structure or are they being submitted as queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're pulling from `/category/geografi/succes`

You could use something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&x=$2&action=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&x=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thx it works but not with this characters (-_) and i need them :S

Comment: RewriteRule ^u/([a-zA-Z0-9-_/]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-_/]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-_/]+)/?$ user-profile.php?username=$1&navigation=$2&frame=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^u/([a-zA-Z0-9-_/]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-_/]+)/?$ user-profile.php?username=$1&navigation=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^u/([a-zA-Z0-9-_/]+)/?$ user-profile.php?username=$1 [L]